# Can sims move to a new neighbourhood?

Tags: the-sims-3

I got the late night expansion pack for the sims, and i'd like to move my family to the new neighbourhood that came with it.

I tried it before but they lost all their money, which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot move sims between neighborhoods, because in Sims3 (unlike in the Sims 2) the Neighborhood *is* the save file*.

What you *can* do, is upload the family in question to the House bins, move to the new neighborhood, and then place them from the housing bin back in the world. However, this eliminates all non-household relations for the sims in question.

*Though I suppose the whole point of the World Adventures expansion is moving to foreign neighborhoods.

Answer (score 3):

Save your sim to the library so you get to save your money and progress such as skills. **Or** save a family *and* home all together to the library then go into neighborhood you want and place them where you want.

I've done it enough to know it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the 'save the entire house' option, if you just save the sims back to the bin they will lose their stats, happiness, etc. Save them in their house and they retain everything.